# Retrieve view references with jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, view, reference

As title says, how can I get the info of a view using jdbc?
For example, my view is:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS
SELECT id AS testid, name, gender, age
FROM mentor
```

How can I know the testview is referencing from table mentor?
And the corresponding columns?

Comment: I'm not aware of a generic JDBC way of doing this, but what RDBMS are you using? There are specific solutions for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `view definition(DDL)` from the database, and use `regular expressions` to find out the table name(s) between `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses. Should be simpler, provided, the user id the `jdbc` uses to connect to the database, should have that privilege!